# Java: Need explanation about a JAVA program output

Tags: java, arrays

I have this program in Java, but I don't know how it works.

```
0;
1; 2;
2; 3; 4;
```

Will someone to explain it to me?

```
public class TestArray
{
  public static void main(String [] args)
  {
    int [][] myArray = new int[3][];
    for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++)
    {
      myArray[i] = new int[i + 1];
      for (int j = 0; j < myArray[i].length; j++)
      {
        myArray[i][j] = i + j;
      }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++)
    {
      for (int j = 0; j < myArray[i].length; j++)
         System.out.print(myArray[i][j] + "; ");
      System.out.println();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It would help if you could explain what you *expected* and why. Have you tried stepping through the code? What do you expect the contents of the array to be after the first half of the program?

Comment: You should debug the code first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a very unspecific question. What is is, that you don't understand?

But I'll give it a try:

The code defines a two dimensinal array of numbers and initializes the first dimension with 3.
The second dimension is initialized as new array with the size of it's index in the first dimension +1 (as the array is zero based).
Each item of the array will get the sum of it's index as value. and print it out in a loop.

The arry looks like this:

```
[0]  
[1][2]  
[2][3][4]
```

because

```
[index 0,0]  
[index 1,0][index 1,1]  
[index 2,0][index 2,1][index 2,2]
```

Answer (score 2):

For each iteration of the first for loop you would get:

**i = 0**, myArray[i].length = 1, **j = 0**      `i+j-> o;`

**i = 1**, myArray[i].length = 2, **j= 0,1**     `i+j-> 1;2;`

**i = 2**, myArray[i.lenght = 3, **j= 0,1,2**    `i+j-> 2;3;4;`